# Slider conflicts with TrackballControls

Tags: three.js

three.js r.71

I've used jquery to apply a simple slider which rotate an object by "z" axis.

http://jsfiddle.net/pf15nz7m

Unfortunately moving slider is also moving camera on the scene.

I am using `TrackballControls`.

```
controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
```

**Question**: How to "turn off" moving camera while using slider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `TrackballControls` (or `OrbitControls`) is reponding to mouse movements outside of the canvas, you need to add the `domElement` argument to the controls constructor.

```
controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pf15nz7m/1/

three.js r.71